# Can't update node

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I'm trying [this](http://davidwalsh.name/upgrade-nodejs) to update my node version, in order to be able to install i18next,
but I get this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'
at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:337:11)
at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:375:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/sha/index.js:3:48)
at Module._compile (module.js:446:26)
at Object..js (module.js:464:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:311:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
If you need help, you may report this log at:
<http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
or email it to:
<npm-@googlegroups.com>
System Darwin 11.4.2
command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "n"
cwd /Users/personalcomputer/Desktop
node -v v0.6.18
npm -v 1.3.5

Additional logging details can be found in:
/Users/personalcomputer/Desktop/npm-debug.log
not ok code undefined
not ok code 1
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: try update npm first : $ sudo npm install -g npm

Comment: I get the same error. It's possible that nmp isn't accessible globally?